# Bootstrap column spanning is not working as I am expecting.. I can't get a button to span entire width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have 2 rows:

- First row a 4span that has a label with a text box below.
- Second an 8 with a label and text box below.

Then a 12 span on second row with a button spanning the entire thing.
I've included an image on how I want it to look and the code I am using.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Merchant:" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="comMerchants" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Enter Pass Serial (GUID):" Width="100%"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGUID" runat="server" Width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" width="100%"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Your markup is standard and should work without outside influence.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use bootstrap to style your form elements too, you're just fighting against the framework otherwise.

So your button probably needs a btn class and then the btn-default (or similar) you can then use btn-block to make it display block rather than inline.

That will make it 100% the width of the container.

If you want *truly* 100% then you will also need to remove the padding from the containing column which I cant remember if you can do in bootstrap3 but you can easily do yourself with your own CSS.

[Like This](https://jsfiddle.net/jd8qoke2/)

The main thing here is the btn, btn-default and btn-block classes on the button.

```
    <button type="Button" ID="Button1" class="btn btn-default btn-block">THIS IS A BUTTON</button>
```

in the fiddle above I have converted your server controls to HTML to make it render properly in the browser and I have applied styling to the column, button and divs (Made the outline purple to make it easier to see them).

Comment: I tried that... but the whole OnClick="btnGetData_Click" won't work.

Comment: Not sure if you found a resolution - BUT  OnClick="btnGetData_Click" is a server side event so the button will need to be a server control but with the same principals applied to it, you wont be able to just swap it out for the code I gave you.

You would need to use CssClass="btn btn-default btn-block" on your <asp:Button

Remember that the code in your aspx is going to be parsed into HTML by the framework so the output HTML might not be what you expect it to be... Its probably worth looking at the HTML rendered in the browser and comparing it to what you expect to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you use Bootstrap Grid row, everything in that row div will be laid out in a single row if possible.

your button has the class of col-md-12, which means that it will take up 12 columns for displays that are smaller then or roughly the same size as a medium display.

If you were to write col-12, it will use up all 12 columns on all screen sizes. but col-md-12 won't. Writing width 100% does one thing. It uses up the what's left of the columns of the row

For a better understanding of bootstrap grid I recommend:

Creating a Responsive Layout with Bootstrap Grid By Shawn Wildermuth - on
pluralsight.com

Or check out the documentation from Bootstrap itself.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I tried col-12 ... it didn't seem to have any effect. :(

Comment: Oh... and I've seen that article before ... and it made me think that the layout code I was using above would work, with variable width columns. over a few rows...  but it didn't work out.